# Copying the address of a loop variable in Go

Tags: for-loop, go, reference

In the following code sample, the result is not what I would expect:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    src := map[int]int{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
    fmt.Println("src ", src)

    dst := make([]*int, 0, len(src))
    for k, _ := range src {
        dst = append(dst, &k)
    }
    for _, a := range dst {
        fmt.Print(*a, " ")
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

Result:

```
src map[1:1 2:2 3:3]
3 3 3
```

Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/BSDsd3nojz

but I understand what is happening. The unchanging address of `k` is being added to `dst`, so when I loop over `dst`, the same value is in every location: `3`.

The address of `k` never changes in the loop, so the second loop keeps referring to that location, containing the last value it had, `3`.

How can I get the address of the current value of `k` to be copied? Do I need something like this:

```
for k, _ := range src {
    key = new(int)
    *key = k
    dst = append(dst, key)
}
```

That seems awkward.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Why do you want int pointers at all? Seems like you are just trying to collect all map keys?

Comment: If you want a copy of the value, you need to copy the value. Your last example is one way, but why are you trying to get a pointer to a copy of the index value of a for loop in the first place?

Comment: The loop variables are allocated once. The map key/value are copied into the same location on each iteration. You should not depend on the address of those, as they have no connection to the address in the underlying map.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do. I found this situation when working with the Go SDK for Google Cloud Datastore. I need an `[]*datastore.Key` to pass to some of the functions. I have a `map[datastore.Key]interface{}`.

Comment: @ralph, yeah, that makes a little more sense than ints.

Comment: I was trying to make a short sample that didn't need hundreds of lines. :-) The pattern of copying from an `x` to a `*x` when traversing a `map` is what I am interested in.

Comment: "the address of the current value of `k`" doesn't make any sense. You can only get the address of a variable, where the current value of `k` is stored - a value that will change whenever `k` is changed. There is no separate address of the current value that changes when the value changes. That isn't how programs use memory.

Comment: I realized that when I was debugging the code. That I why I came up with the alternate, correct code. I was hoping for a shorter version of my code. See @captncraig's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45967429/96233).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a `map[T]X` and you want to get a `[]*T`, you are on the right track with copying the loop variable and getting an address to it.

There is a slightly slimmer way to do it than your way:

```
for k := range src {
    key := k
    dst = append(dst, &key)
}
```

What you are adding to dst is not the address of the keys or values in the map, but rather the address of a **copy** of the key. That distinction may or may not matter to you.

The reason that using the address of the loop variables doesn't work, is that the loop variables are single locations that get updated on each iteration. Value types like ints and structs are copyed each time you assign it to a new variable.

Comment: I almost tried that, but then I thought that the compiler would only allocate a single location for `key` and I would have the same problem. I guess I should have tried it.

Comment: Yeah, this is a common gotcha in go. The scope of `key` is inside the loop, so it is limited to this iteration. Not sure what kind of escape analysis leads to it getting allocated on heap vs stack, but it does work.

Comment: It's also actually common to see `k := k` to shadow the variable with the same name. It's not escape analysis, the lexical scoping says the new declaration is valid for the remainder of the block.

Comment: @JimB what I was getting at was: if you never add `key` to `dst`, the compiler could re-use a single stack location for every iteration. Saving it to the slice means it can't be overwritten. I don't know enough about the compiler to know how that works.

Comment: @captncraig: Ah, I see what you mean. That is an _optimization_ that can be made, but it's not anything you would ever need to be aware of. If you ever use `&i`, it's going to escape, so escape analysis prevents it. Here's an unsafe example that makes sure the pointer doesn't escape: https://play.golang.org/p/6rVGNZHe5K ;) (at least as of go1.9)

Comment: If what you want a pointer to the original elements, your code don't work as intended. You are getting pointers of the copies of the original elements. 

https://go.dev/play/p/AtN3u9otkwQ

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the array indices for iteration, rather than values. This way you can reference the original objects instead of copying them around:

```
    for i, _ := range src {
        dst = append(dst, &src[i])
    }
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it. Because the accepted answer is getting pointers of the copies of the original elements, instead of pointers to the original elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use array indices to avoid values duplication. Example: building a map index

```golang
type User struct {
  id int
  ...
}

func (u *User) ID() int {
  return u.id
}

users := []User{ ... }

indexByID := make(map[int]&User, len(users))
for i := range users {
  p := &users[i]
  indexByID[p.ID()] = &p
}
```